# How to find the column name to write in excel cell

Tags: java

I am using eclipse, selenium web driver, apache POI, java. I am very new to this and java.

I have xls file with 3 columns: email, pw, result. I have 3 rows of data. Result column is blank.

Each iteration, script should read email and pw and then perform action. Then write result in Result column.

Continue until it reaches the last row.

I hard coded the column number and it works. I am not able to figure out how to find the column number with header "result" and then how to write in the cell for the corresponding row.

```
    File file =    new File("C://dd.xls");

    try {
        // Open the Excel file
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Access the required test data sheet
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
        int TotalRow;
        int TotalCol;
        TotalRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        TotalCol = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        System.out.println("row " + TotalRow +  " col " +  TotalCol);


        // Loop through all rows in the sheet
        // Start at row 1 as row 0 is our header row
        for(int count = 1;count<=sheet.getLastRowNum();count++){
            //for(int col = 1;col<=TotalCol;col++){


             HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(count);
             System.out.println("Running test case " + row.getCell(0).toString() +  " " +  row.getCell(1).toString());
             HSSFCell hSSFCell = row.getCell(TotalCol-1);
             String value = count + "aa";
             hSSFCell.setCellValue(value);}
          // }
        fis.close();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        wb.write(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Test data file not found");
}
```

[image]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jqefYaffunknolrj6i4SXOoq2LiKT3xTgSsdzaxsBfQ

Comment: Starts from A1 and read cell's text  (A2, A3 etc) and break when you find your header???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
    int TotalRow;
    int TotalCol;
    TotalRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    HSSFRow headerRow = sheet.getRow(0);
    String result = "";
    int resultCol = -1;
    for (Cell cell : headerRow){
        result = cell.getStringCellValue();
        if (result.equals("Result"){
            resultCol = cell.getColumnIndex();
            break;
         }
    }
    if (resultCol == -1){
        System.out.println("Result column not found in sheet");
        return;
    }   
    System.out.println("row " + TotalRow +  " col " +  TotalCol);


    // Loop through all rows in the sheet
    // Start at row 1 as row 0 is our header row
    for(int count = 1;count<=sheet.getLastRowNum();count++){
         HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(count);
         System.out.println("Running test case " + row.getCell(0).toString() +  " " +  row.getCell(1).toString());
         HSSFCell hSSFCell = row.getCell(resultCol);
         String value = count + "aa";
         hSSFCell.setCellValue(value);}
      // }
    fis.close();
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    wb.write(outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Thank you but I am getting error. Please see above for the errors. If you need additional info, I can provide you.

Comment: Which version of java, POI did you use? For that code, I propose you using java 8 and apache POI 3.15

Comment: Java 1.8  Apache POI 3.9. Please see above google doc for the errors.

Comment: Thank you but I still have errors. We are down to two errors. Could you please look at the google doc again?

Comment: I fixed the second error by adding ")". So first error is not fixed.

Comment: Let's change the `HSSFCell` to `Cell` and import the right package for the `Cell` class: `import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;` You should know that `HSSFCell` is implement the interface `Cell` have a look at [this](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html)